# Mounting home directory in Visual Studio docker environment

Tags: visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core

I have the following configuration in my .csproj file to mount my AWS credentials when running .NET core in a Docker container:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>True</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <DockerfileRunArguments>-v /C/Users/myname/.aws:/root/.aws</DockerfileRunArguments>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

However, I need this to work across different development environments. I've tried replacing `myname` with `${env.UserName}` or `%USERNAME%` but in both cases I get `Error response from daemon: mkdir C:\Users\[variable is here]: Access is denied.`

The docker run command is fine if I hard-code my user name as shown.

Comment: seems like your are mounting the windows directory, in this you have to add the Users group to the .docker folder and grant full access.please follow this https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3385#issuecomment-501931980

Comment: It works if I hard-code the name, so I think it more of a variable value and/or parsing issue than actually a permission problem? If I understood what context (shell, user) the docker run command was been run in that might help.